# How is instantaneous frequency defined for electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: radio-frequency

I've been trying to understand the frequency modulation used in radio signals.  According to Wikipedia, FM radio encodes signals as variations in the instantaneous frequency, which is defined as $\omega (t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{dt}(t)$.  I understand how this would apply to rotational frequency, but how would you apply this formula to something that is not rotating, like electromagnetic radiation?  I just don't understand how it's applicable.

Comment: So you are saying that modulating the carrier phase will not result in a modulation in the frequency?

Comment: No, I'm asking how this formula can be applied to a carrier phase frequency when there is no rotation, since $\theta$ is a measure of the angle.  I'm not really well versed in physics, so this is all foreign territory for me.

Comment: $\omega$ is not a rotational frequency of anything *real*. In signal processing it is *convenient* to introduce the I and Q components of hte complex phasor and in that picture $\omega$ is the rotation frequency of the phasor but *nature* is not *picture*.

Comment: No instantaneous observation determines a frequency.   The language is used loosely, meaning short-time-scale (a microsecond) compared to

Answer (score 1):

Phase is rotating. It goes 0 to 360 degrees. That phase is depicted in a diagram that has an angle $\theta$.

If you write the wave as $ s(t) = A\cos{(2\pi f_0t+ \phi{(t))}}$, with $f_0$ constant, then

$\theta = (2\pi(f_0t+ \phi{(t))})$ is the phase

$\frac{d\theta}{dt}(t) = (2\pi f_0 + \frac{d\phi}{dt}(t))$

You can work with $\theta$, the full phase, or $\phi$, the part of the phase that is changing. $\theta$ includes what is sometime called the carrier

The total instantaneous frequency is then

$f = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{dt}(t) = f_0 + \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{d\phi}{dt}(t)$

and you can see that if frequency is constant you get what you expect.

The graph of $\theta$ is best seen then in a graphic as the angle a vector (or a line with length A) makes with the x axis as it rotates in a circle, centered at (0,0), where A is the circle radius, and it is rotating around at the rate $theta$ changes. A circularly rotating vector (or line if you wish, with length A). Also called a phasor (but with amplitude A)

The good thing about this definition is that it shows the instantaneous frequency, as the instantaneous rate of change of phase. It is understood that phase modulation changes the frequency also, except for a constant phase change (which is anyway just a constant frequency).

Another way of plotting the phase is by splitting the complex signal (see below) into I and Q components, where I is the real part (so called in-phase), and Q the imaginary part (so called quadrature), and I is horizontal while Q is vertical. It's the identical result with the so called analytic or complex signal $s_a(t) = A exp (i\theta(t))$, since the tangent is just the sine over the cosine.

So, it's the angle a vector spinning around makes with the x axis. That vector going around represented as a complex number is a phasor (with amplitude A).

It is not just in signal processing (extremely useful when estimating frequency digitally, using various points near $t = t_0$, with $t_0$ being where you need the instantaneous value -- always just an estimate with real waves or radio signals), but also in modulation design or analysis, and in estimating/calculating theoretical bit error rates, the I/Q graphic and representation is most useful. A plot on an I/Q diagram of quadrature phase key modulation (digital) is 4 points, at 0, 90,180, and 270 degrees, at a distance A from the center. How far apart those points are pretty much determines, along with signal to noise ratio, the bit error rates. For a 256 PSK it has 256 points, much tighter, and much higher bit error rates.

Answer (score 0):

How, indeed, can we define instantaneous frequency?

No instantaneous observation can ever determine a frequency.   The language is used loosely, "instantaneous" meaning short-time-scale.

An FM broadcast station might broadcast at 100 MHz (ten nanoseconds period for each cycle), with modulation at audio frequency (hundreds to thousands of microseconds per cycle for the audio signal).

One would observe many ten-nanosecond electric cycles in a microsecond,
and that suffices to measure a frequency in the interval t=(0... 1 microsecond).  A second frequency measurement that takes place at t= (100 ...101 microsecond)
could be different, and those long-duration differences are the 'modulation'
that gives FM its second letter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with the idea of an electric field, then you know it can be characterized as a vector associated with each point of space at some instant of time, $\vec{E}(\vec{x},t)$.

If we have an antenna, which is a straight rod along the $\hat{z}$ direction for instance, an electromagnetic wave will push the electrons along the rod with a force proportional to the projection of the vector along the direction $\hat{z}$. Mathematically we have $F_z = q (\hat{z} \cdot \vec{E}(\vec{x},t))$, and we are saying that at some distinct point in space a pure, coherent, electromagnetic wave follows the $|E(\vec{x}_0, t)| \propto A\sin(\omega t)$.

If such an electromagnetic wave is incident on an antenna at the point $\vec{x}_0$, the electrons in the antenna are pushed to and fro with a frequency $\omega$. That is the frequency which is measured and modulated by the receiver. In general, an electromagnetic wave will be the sum of many of such terms $A_i \sin(\omega_i t)$, and FM radio works by sending many pure waves with frequencies near the value which you dial into your radio.

Since you mentioned understanding angular frequencies, we can actually use another picture which comes from working out the physics in the complex plane. If we look at the electromagnetic field strength, the length of the vector $\vec{E}(\vec{x},t)$ along the $\hat{z}$ direction for instance, in the complex plane, and we take the real part of the number to be the strength of the electric field, then we actually will have an oscillation about a circle just as you imagined. This is normally called the [Phasor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) description.